# Updating Firmware on GTX 650

Tags: graphics-card, bios, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, firmware

**GOAL**

- I would like to update the firmware on my GTX 650 ( GV-N650OC-2GT) it has the original firmware on it " 80.07.35.00.5F " that I would like to upgrade to the latest " 80.07.35.00.9D ".

**WHY.**

- The reason for the upgrade because the old firmware has " UEFI Supported: No " and the newer version has " UEFI Supported: Yes ". I need it to be able to to use the GPU to be a passthrough GPU for a Virtual box.

**HOW.**

- I am using "nvflash" on windows 10 64 bit. I got the folder in the command prompt and just type in to command prompt

```
nvflash --protectoff
nvflash NEWGPUBIOSNAME.rom
```

As it is in many guide says the screen start flashing and I get no error message. It opens a separate command prompt window and runs there quiet quickly and also closes so I  am not sure that it runs perfectly. But it does not changes the GPU firmware. I check the firmware name with the techpowerup GPU-Z.2.38.0 software and even with restarting the software the firmware stays the same.

**Possible Errors**

- techpowerup website I have downloaded for the correct exact card GV-N650OC-2GT because I still have the original box with this sticker ( GV-N650OC-2GT) and the card also matches the image and all the other specification.

Comment: When you run `nvflash --protectoff` do you get any sort of output?  What is that output?

Comment: ```nvflash --protectoff ```  also opens a separate window, runs commands very quickly, darkens the screen for 1 second. I don't have the opportunity to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

*80.07.35.00.58* what is 1 version older firmware that sill have " UEFI Supported: Yes " installs. For now this solves the problem. It runs slowly in the newly opened window and it also stops to ask for permission for the update. After updating techpowerup GPU-Z.2.38.0 shows the new firmware.

The latest firmware  " 80.07.35.00.9D " runs very quickly, darkens the screen for 1 second. I don't have the opportunity to check for errors.